# Class Linker Error Code

Tags: c++, linker

I am writting this basic program and am stuck.  I am new to C++. My program has to
**calulate a fine for various offenses**.
It will accomplish this by:

1. The user will input the actual speed, speed limit, wether the 
   offense occured in a work zone/ residential area/ or not, and the court fees
2. Display the total amount for the ticket
3. Prompt the user if they wish to enter another ticket or quit

This is an example of expected output:

> Speeding
>   Fine: $5 per mile over speed limit  plus Court Fees
>
> Speeding Highway Work Zone
>   Fine: $6 per mile over speed limit plus Court Fees
>
> Speeding in a Residential District
>   Fine: $7 per mile over speed limit plus $200 plus Court Fees

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

class FineCalculator
{
public:
    ~FineCalculator() {}
    FineCalculator(int courtFees); 
    int getFine(int zone, int speedLimit, int actualSpeed) const;

private:
  int courtFees;
  int balance;
};


FineCalculator::FineCalculator(int courtFees)
{
    //return courtFees;
}

int getFine(int zone, int speedLimit, int actualSpeed) 
{
    //define IF you are speeding or not

    if (actualSpeed > speedLimit)
    {

        /* define speeding zones
           1. Regular
           2. Highway
           3. Residential
         */

        if (zone==1)
        {
            int balanceCounter=actualSpeed-speedLimit;

        //balance=courtfees+(loopcounter*5)
        //balance
        }

    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int courtFee=0;
    int inputFee=0;
    int accumulator=0;
    int programLooper=1; 
    int speedLimitz=0;
    int vechicleSpeed=0;

    std::cout<<"Please enter the court fee $";
    std::cin >>courtFee;

    FineCalculator fine1(courtFee);

    while (programLooper !=0)
    {
        //1 for regular, 2 for highway, 3 for residential
        //loop selection of offenses
        std::cout<<"Please make numerical  ticket selection for where the offense occured: \n";
        std::cout<<"1. Regular \n";
        std::cout<<"2. Highway \n";
        std::cout<<"3. Residential \n";
        std::cin >>programLooper;

        std::cout<<"\n \n \n";
        std::cout<<"Please Enter the speed limit \n";
        std::cin >>speedLimitz;

        std::cout<<"\n \n \n";
        std::cout<<"Please Enter the vechile speed  \n";
        std::cin >>vechicleSpeed;

        fine1.getFine(programLooper,speedLimitz,vechicleSpeed);
    }

    if (programLooper==0)
    {
        //end program loop
        return (0);
    }
}
```

For starters on the `FineCalculator::FineCalculator(int courtFees)` method I am not sure what to type in the return because anything after return I type gives an error.

Also on the `fine1.getFine(programLooper,speedLimitz,vechicleSpeed);` I get an error saying :

```
Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall FineCalculator::getFine(int,int,int)const " (?getFine@FineCalculator@@QBEHHHH@Z) referenced in function _main
```

**What is going on here?  I am completely stumped.**

Comment: Don't use tabs directly in markdown text. Use 4 spaces instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define the function like this:

```
int getFine(int zone, int speedLimit, int actualSpeed)
{ ... }
```

you're defining an ordinary function, not part of your class - which is legal, but not what you want.

To define the `getFine` you declared in your class you need:

```
int FineCalculator::getFine(int zone, int speedLimit, int actualSpeed) const
{ ... }
```

(The `FineCalculator::` is the key. You also need the final const to match how you declared it.)

Also, for your first question, you can't return anything from `FineCalculator::FineCalculator`. But you don't need to - it's job is to construct a `FineCalculator` object which you can then use, for example by calling `getFine` on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the 'const' in :

```
int getFine(int zone, int speedLimit, int actualSpeed) const;
```

Comment: It should be `const` - it doesn't (and shouldn't) modify the class.

Answer (score 0):

In `class FineCalculator`, you declared `getFine` method const, but you defined it without const. To fix the linking error, you need to make both declaration and definition to be const or non-const.

Answer (score 0):

Both compiler and linker need to know if the member function is `const`.
Hence not only while declaring the function it should be qualified but also while defining it.

Also, the scope isn't resolved when defining it, use the scope resolution operator `::` to indicate that it belongs to the class.

Answer (score 0):

yes, the const needs to be removed.
What was the motivation in declaring getfine as a const, since you are anyway modifying the object?